# What is the final product of a carbohydrate treated successively with hydrogen cyanide, water, and hydrogen iodide/ phosphorus?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, carbohydrates

> An unknown carbohydrate is successively treated with (1) hydrogen cyanide, (2) water, and (3) hydrogen iodide and phosphorus:
>   $$\ce{C6H12O6 ->[HCN] X ->[H2O] Y ->[HI,P]Z}$$
>   What is the final product $\ce{Z}$?

I could figure out that in $\ce{Y}$ there is a $\ce{CH(OH)(COOH)}$ group instead of a $\ce{CHO}$ group, but I could not find out $\ce{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your starting material is an unspecified hexose ($\ce{C6H12O6})$. Leaving the stereochemistry aside, it is either an aldose or a ketose.

[image: Reaction scheme]

1. Addition of $\ce{HCN}$ results in the formation of **X**, a cyanohydrin (α-hydroxy nitrile) with seven carbon atoms ($\ce{C7H13NO6})$.
2. Hydrolysis of **X** yields the α-hydroxy carboxylic acid **Y** ($\ce{C7H14O8})$.
3. The reaction of **Y** with $\ce{P_{red}/HI}$ is likely to result in reductive dehydroxylation. Overall, the oxygen atom of the carbonyl group in **X** has been replaced with $\ce{H}$ and a $\ce{COOH}$ group.
   **Z** therefore is $\ce{C7H14O7}$.